# Clion : Is there anyway to run wsl as a specific user

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion

I noticed that Clion supports running projects on wsl subsystem, which is very convenient for coding on the Windows system. However, all command are running as root, and I only find the terminal can pre-run the shell scripts to change the user, but other tools such as cmake, git can not be changed running with specific users. Since all my tools are configured well on a specific user such as Conan etc. Is there any way to change the login user for cmake, git tools to use the CLion IDE?
[image: shell settings]

[image: all built-in tools are running as root]